# Swift - Read nested structures with for loop

Tags: swift, xcode, nested, bluetooth-lowenergy, structure

I'm trying to read nested structures with a for loop in my BLE project. The main purpose is to update a global structure with new values from my peripheral. In total i have maybe 60 attributes, so using a loop would help me a lot.

The structures are:

```
/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Attributes structure
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
struct IthetisAttribute
{
    let UUID: String
    let Length: UInt8
    let Service: String
    var Value: UInt32
}

/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Pump state profile
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
struct IthetisPump_state
{
    /* Steps from start: 0xFFF1 and 3 byte */
    static var StepsFromStart : IthetisAttribute =
        IthetisAttribute(UUID: "FFF1", Length: 3,
                         Service: IthetisConstant.STATE_SERVICE_UUID, Value: 0)

    /* Steps of current dose : 0xFFF2 and 3 byte */
    static var StepsCurrent : IthetisAttribute =
        IthetisAttribute(UUID: "FFF2", Length: 3,
                         Service: IthetisConstant.STATE_SERVICE_UUID, Value: 0)

/* ... */ 
}
```

Now I'm trying to take out the attributes structures from IthetisPump_state, to check the UUID. I first tried something like that :

```
for attr: IthetisAttribute in IthetisPump_state
{
    /* ... */
}
```

But it does not work obviously. So I tried something else :

```
let Profile = IthetisPump_state()
for attr: IthetisAttribute in Mirror(reflecting: Profile).children
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Xcode is telling me that Mirror.child is not convertible to IthetisAttribute. I tried several other techniques but I always end up with an error.

What is the best way to go through nested structures ?
Thanks in advance !

-- Update, following the answer of Lorenzo ---

I tried this way: I created a new structure with arrays (it worked, but then I tried to use pointers)

```
struct IthetisPump_profiles
{
    /* State profile */
    static var State: [UnsafePointer<IthetisAttribute>] =
    [
        &IthetisPump_state.StepsFromStart,
        &IthetisPump_state.StepsCurrent,
        /* ... */
    ]
}
```

On my main code now I use something like this :

```
var Attribute_counter = 0
for attr: IthetisAttribute in IthetisPump_profiles.State
{
    if characteristic.uuid.description.isEqual(attr.UUID)
    {
        let temp: UInt32 = SharedMethods.ConvertDataToUInt32(characteristic.value!,
                                                             byteLength:attr.Length)

        IthetisPump_profiles.State[Attribute_counter].Value = temp

        if(attr.UUID == "FFF1")
        {
            print("UUID \(IthetisPump_state.StepsFromStart.UUID)
                value is \(IthetisPump_state.StepsFromStart.Value)")
            print("UUID \(IthetisPump_profiles.State[0].UUID)
                value is \(IthetisPump_profiles.State[0].Value)")
        }
    }
    Attribute_counter = Attribute_counter + 1
}
```

The first line (with state.StepsFromStart) is giving me 0 and the other one (with State[0]) gives me the right number. 
I may use an enumeration because it is simple, but how could I implement a solution with pointers ? 
Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. First of all you have mixed `static` with instance declarations. I would change a little bit.

About your question, you could use KVC. Here a simple example:

```
struct IthetisAttribute {
    let UUID: String
    let length: UInt8
    let service: String
    var value: UInt32
}

struct IthetisPump_state {
    let states = [
        IthetisAttribute(UUID: "1", length: 9, service: "", value: 1),
        IthetisAttribute(UUID: "2", length: 9, service: "", value: 1),
        IthetisAttribute(UUID: "3", length: 9, service: "", value: 1),
        IthetisAttribute(UUID: "4", length: 9, service: "", value: 1),
        IthetisAttribute(UUID: "5", length: 9, service: "", value: 1)
    ]
}

let pump = IthetisPump_state()    
for i in 0..<pump.states.count {
    print(pump[keyPath:\IthetisPump_state.states[i].UUID])
}
```

If you need to handle something more complex, you can use `enum` with associated values.

Let me know for anything.

P.S. Instance variable should have start lower letters. e.g. `service` instead of `Service`

Comment: Thank you for your response, it resolve a part of my problem. With your method I can not access directly to a specific Attribute. An enumeration may be a good solution indeed. I was trying to create an array of pointers to update the structures values but my Swift knowledge is insufficient. I will update my post to show you.